# Error al ejecutar Script de python en cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, script, cmd

estoy comenzando en python y antes ejecutaba mis scripts desde cmd y en la misma consola me arrrojaba los resultados ahora me abre una ventana nueva se ejecuta y se cierra de inmediato sin ver los resultaados del script aguien me podria ayudar para que me ejecute todo en cmd como antes lo hacia?

Comment: ¿Y, específicamente, cómo lo ejecutabas anteriormente? Pulsa en [edit] para mostrar los comandos que utilizabas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrias intentar reinstalar python por si tienes problema por alguna actualización o cambio. Una vez lo instales asegurate de marcar Add To Path para que se agregue a las variables de entorno.

Si todo queda bien configurado es navegar hasta tu carpeta dónde tienes los scripts con CD nombre_carpeta y ejecutar con python nombre_archivo.py

si esto no te funciona valida las variables de entorno en Path que si tengas las rutas de instalación de python y su carpeta Scritps.

Para comprobar la instalación podrías usar python --version

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).